# Problema con Menu lateral

Tags: php, html

estoy corrigiendo la página de la empresa donde trabajo y tiene unos problemillas, le puse un menu lateral como pidió el jefe pero tengo el problema que cuando se va a otra sección y das clic en menú se va a home de nuevo

este es mi código del boton del menu:

```
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="glyphicon btn-menu toggle">
                                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                                    </a>
```

y aquí lo que va en la parte lateral

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <nav id="spy">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">
                        <a href="index.php" style="color:#de3053; font-size: 20px;">
                        <strong>
                            BOOSTERWISE
                        </strong>
                    </a>
                    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
contenido de página
</div>
</div>
```

aquí el Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*Menu-toggle*/
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

/*Scroll Spy*/
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#spy', offset:80});

/*Smooth link animation*/
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

solo requiero que no se vaya a home...

[Página en la que estoy trabajando](http://boosterwise.com/)

Comment: El boton  BOOSTERWISE tiene un link directo a index.php, siempre te va a recargar la pagina.
Describe un poco mas en detalle cual es el resultado esperado (y el no esperado)

Comment: hola si tiene un enlace al index pero el problema está cuadno abres el menu y vas a galería o noticias. estando en galería o noticias intentas abrir el menu (el simbolo de menú) y te redirige a la pagina principal y es lo que no quiero

Answer (score 0):

En esta pagina (lamentablemente esta en ingles) solucionan el mismo problema que tienes tu, reemplaza tu codigo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string
            .replace(/^\//, '')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
            .replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        if (filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname) && location.hostname == this.hostname && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $targetId = $(this.hash),
                $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
            if ($target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, 400);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> JQuery is still hijacking links that have an inline onclick handler (but, oddly, only the first time those links are clicked). To fix this problem, we can replace the .click() with .each()

[Link de interes](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links)

Comment: gracias lo revisare :D

Comment: como puedo editar mi código JS? es que en JS soy muy muy nuevo

Comment: @OscarEduardoCrespoCouoh debes borrar el script que pusiste en tu pregunta y reemplazar el que te deje yo

Comment: gracias lo hice pero no funcionó, lo intentaré nuevamente creo algo hice mal :S

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres poner a la derecha el menú que por defecto te lo pone boostrap es lo mas sencillo.

POR DEFECTO VIENE ASI

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
```

Lo que aquí esta ordenando con el **`"mr-auto"`** es que el MARGEN DERECHO SEA AUTOMÁTICO es decir que todo se vaya a la izquierda, "mr"= Margen Right (margen derecho).

Entonces si tu escribes

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Le estas ordenando que el menú se vaya a la derecha porque

```
"ml-auto" = MARGEN IZQUIERDO SEA AUTOMÁTICO. 
"ml"= Margen Left.
```

En conclusión todo es a la inversa
"mr" si deseas el menú a la izquierda y "ml" si deseas el menú a la derecha.

Comment: No hay bootstrap aca...